# Parse data to nested JSON

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to create nested JSON. I getting data from sql table.
Data Format in table:

```
+---------------------+---------+
|    Domain           |  Action |
+---------------------+---------+
| Keyword             |  New    |
| Keyword             |  Edit   |
| Keyword             |  Delete |
| Keyword.Case        |  New    |
| Keyword.Case        |  Edit   |
| Keyword.Case        |  Delete |
| Keyword.Case.Action |  New    |
| Keyword.Case.Action |  Edit   |
| Keyword.Case.Action |  Delete |
| User                |  New    |
| User                |  Edit   |
| User                |  Delete |
+---------------------+---------+
```

I have retrieved the data from sql table using linq query. And Now i want to parse it to get hierarchical structure mentioned below. 
I think data should be in following format:

```
[
 {
   "Domain": "Keyword",
   "Actions": ["New", "Edit", "Delete"],
   "Nodes": [
             {
               "Domain": "Keyword.Case",
               "Actions": ["New", "Edit", "Delete"],
               "Nodes": [
                         {
                          "Domain": "Keyword.Case.Action",
                          "Actions": ["New", "Edit", "Delete"],
                          "Nodes": []
                          }
                         ]
              }
             ],
 {
   "Domain": "User",
   "Actions": ["New", "Edit", "Delete"],
   "Nodes": []
 }
]
```

---

Dot (.) means that it is child node. 
For example keyword.case.action; In this example Keyword is parent of Case and Case is parent of Action means action is child of case and case is child of keyword. I want something like that:

- Keyword

  - Edit
  - Delete
  - New
  - Keyword.Case

    - Edit
    - Delete
    - New
    - Keyword.Case.Action
    - Edit
    - Delete
    - New
- User

  - Edit
  - Delete
  - New

Can anyone help please? Thanks in advance

Comment: Pls, provide example data, which you are getting from db.

Comment: the table at the top is the actual data im getting from db. @1ven

Comment: You have a wide range of programming tags there (Angular, C#, SQL) so it is unclear where and what you want to achieve. Show us what you got already Otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: You are getting 1-level json from db?

Comment: Yes im getting 1-level json from db. @1ven

Comment: I want to parse in mvc controller. @OleAlbers

Answer (score 0):

When you retrieve the SQL-Data using LinQ you should have an IEnumerable result. You can serialize that directly:

```
var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
string jsonOutput = serializer.Serialize(dbResult);
```

Where `dbResult` is the result you retrieve after the LinQ-Operation

Comment: Yes. I done that. It is 1-level json. I want to parse in nested level @OleAlbers